# Игнорирование proxy клиента при подключении к VPN

Tags: linux, proxy, l2tp

Занимаюсь организацией ресурса VPN-доступа к интернет-машине, с которой разрешен доступ к ресурсу за прокси. Ранее, в качестве интернет-машины стоял Mikrotik CHR, настроенный также для доступа к интернет и одному ресурсу (который как раз и блочит прокси). На клиентских машинах прописан прокси (http_proxy, https_proxy и socks_proxy). Подключалось по паре "логин-пароль" и общему ключу, прокси не трогалось.
По некоторым причинам пришлось перейти на linux с пакетами strongswan и xl2tpd. Все подключается - но не смотря на появление интернета на клиенте, доступа к ресурсу за прокси нет. При удалении прокси на машине клиента, доступ к ресурсу появляется.

Прошу помощи, как сконфигурировать l2tp-сервер для игнорирования прописанного у клиента прокси. У меня мысли уже кончились - почему на Микротике обходит, а на Linux нет.

**/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
conn rw-base
    fragmentation=yes
    dpdaction=clear
    dpdtimeout=90s
    dpddelay=30s

conn l2tp-vpn
    also=rw-base
    authby=secret
    left=172.16.10.35
    pfs=no
    rekey=no
    right=%any
    type=tunnel
    auto=add
```

**/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd**

```
asyncmap 0
auth
crtscts
lock
hide-password
modem
mtu 1460
lcp-echo-interval 30
lcp-echo-failure 4
noipx
multilink
mppe-stateful
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
```

**/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf**

```
[global]                                                                
port = 1701
auth file = /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
access control = no
ipsec saref = yes
force userspace = yes

[lns default]
exclusive = no
ip range = 10.32.10.2-10.32.10.20
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
flow bit = yes
hidden bit = no
local ip = 10.32.10.1
length bit = yes
refuse pap = yes
require authentication = yes
require chap = yes
name = vks-local
```

**iptables -t nat -L**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```